# How can you convert a webm file format to a wav file using python

Tags: python, wav, file-extension, file-format, webm

i wanted to convert a webm file to a wav file using python. Ik there is already an answer to this but it doesnt work.

My first question is why doesnt my code work?

```
clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip("/Users/xxx/Downloads/1.webm")
clip.audio.write_audiofile("/Users/xxx/Downloads/1.wav")
```

I got this error

```
File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/SecondProject/sound.py", line 13, in <module>
    clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip("/Users/xxx/Downloads/1.webm")
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
  File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/xx/xxx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 35, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/xxx/xx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 289, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    raise IOError(("MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file %s.\n"
OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file /Users/xxx/Downloads/1.webm.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-appkit --enable-avfoundation --enable-coreimage --enable-audiotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/Users/xxx/Downloads/1.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
At least one output file must be specified
```

If anyone thinks they can help with that , that would really help.

Lastly , is there another way to change my webm file to a wav file?

Comment: It seems that the webm video is interrupted. Could you provide that webm file?

Comment: It cant really fit. Is there any other way we can communicate. Such as discord maybe?

Comment: @Keijack , do you have any way we can communicate

Comment: you found any solution?